# Problem with Opening ODS File using Java Code on VMware Virtual Machine

Tags: java, openoffice.org

On a VMware virtual machine, I am the administrator. On this VM, we are running a batch script that calls Java code.
My colleagues are regular users on this VM.
The batch script attempts to open the ODS file with the following Java code.

```
// the boolean property Hidden tells the office to open a file in
// hidden mode
PropertyValue[] props = new PropertyValue[1];
props[0] = new PropertyValue();
props[0].Name = "Hidden";
props[0].Value = new Boolean(true);

XComponent component = xLoader.loadComponentFromURL("file:///" + pathToFile, "_blank", 0, props);

XSpreadsheetDocument document = (XSpreadsheetDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSpreadsheetDocument.class, component);

XSpreadsheets sheets = document.getSheets();
```

The "document" variable is null, which causes a null pointer exception (sometimes, not always) for other users who are not administrators. I have never encountered any issues myself as I am an administrator on the VM.
For your information, `xLoader` is defined as follows:

```
XComponentLoader xLoader = initialiseComponent();
```

and

```
private XComponentLoader initialiseComponent() { 

    try {

        Object x;
        Object defaultContext;
        Object desktop;

        XComponentContext componentContext = Bootstrap
                .createInitialComponentContext(null);
        x = componentContext.getServiceManager().createInstanceWithContext(
                "com.sun.star.connection.Connector", componentContext);
        XConnector connector = (XConnector) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                XConnector.class, x);
        XConnection connection = connector.connect("socket,host="
                + ooService.getConfiguration().getString(
                OPEN_OFFICE_HOST_KEY)
                + ",port="
                + ooService.getConfiguration().getString(
                OPEN_OFFICE_PORT_KEY));
        x = componentContext.getServiceManager().createInstanceWithContext(
                "com.sun.star.bridge.BridgeFactory", componentContext);
        XBridgeFactory bridgeFactory = (XBridgeFactory) UnoRuntime
                .queryInterface(XBridgeFactory.class, x);
        XBridge bridge = bridgeFactory.createBridge("", "urp", connection,
                null);
        x = bridge.getInstance("StarOffice.ServiceManager");
        XMultiComponentFactory multiComponentFactory = (XMultiComponentFactory) UnoRuntime
                .queryInterface(XMultiComponentFactory.class, x);

        XPropertySet properySet = (XPropertySet) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                XPropertySet.class, multiComponentFactory);
        defaultContext = properySet.getPropertyValue("DefaultContext");
        componentContext = (XComponentContext) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                XComponentContext.class, defaultContext);
        multiComponentFactory = componentContext.getServiceManager();
        desktop = multiComponentFactory.createInstanceWithContext(
                "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", componentContext);
        return (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                XComponentLoader.class, desktop);

    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Thank you
Here are the checks that have already been performed:

- We are using the same classpath.
- User Landa has read and write permissions on the file.
- The file exists at the specified path "file:///" + pathToFile, and when I enter "file:///" + pathToFile, I can access the file.
- The issue is most likely caused by the initializeComponent method.